# can't execute conda in terminal ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, bash, anaconda, conda

I have problem about runnig conda command. I've followed all the stackoverflow's answers to this question, but no one worked for me.

```
juldou@juldou-machine:~$ conda --v
conda: command not found
```

I set the PATH in bashrc as follows:

```
export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: Did you source your altered .bashrc? `source ~/.bashrc`. Alternately launch a new terminal

Comment: Where is conda located?

Comment: is `conda` in `~/anaconda3/bin`? If so, is the executable bit set? Look at `ls -l ~/anaconda3/bin`, and post the result here, if you are not sure what I am talking about.

Comment: @Suever this worked for me! What was the problem?

Comment: @JúliusMarko Any time that you make a change to your `.bashrc` file, these changes aren't automatically reflected in the currently active terminals. You need to other reload `.bashrc` in the running terminals or simply open a new terminal (which will load the new `.bashrc`)